# How to add a function to a disabled directive - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

What i want to achieve is to enabled the submit button after it matches the if condition below but the button does not seem to be enabled after the conditions are met.

```
    <button [disabled]="!isFullfilled(m.value, n.value)" type="submit" class="ui button">Submit</button>


  isFullfilled(m: number, n: number) {
    if (
          m === this.restrict_arr.length
          && m === this.xinitial_arr.length
          && m === this.lift_arr.length
          && n === this.param_arr.length
          && n === this.system_arr.length
       ) {
         return true;
       }

       return false;
  }
```

here is a full example [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dHJf8QEhhvU5LupdDcmX?p=preview)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
return false;
```

to

```
return null;
```

Boolean attributes are removed on `null` not on `false`. `false` leads to `disabled="false"`

Comment: i did that but seems i have to call my function somewhere?or can it be checked automatically? i mean the isFullfilled function is not called anywhere except on the disabled directive. Does change detection recall that function or i have to do it manually?

Comment: Change detection should call it repeatedly.

Comment: hmm then what is going on as it does not work. button stays disabled.

Comment: I guess you need to move the distinction between `null` and `true` to the binding expression. `!null` (null returned from the function call) again returns `true`. Use instead `[disabled]="!isFullfilled(m.value, n.value) ? true : null "`. The plunker never returns false, even when all fields are filled. What is the criteria to get `false`?

Comment: did some debugging and put a console.log if the condition was met, but it seems the condition is never met for somereason guess i have something wrong there?

Comment: found it. The triple equals where causing the problem.